# django : recaptcha : Error in firefox works in IE & chrome : RecaptchaState error

Tags: django, firefox, recaptcha

I have integrated Recaptcha with dJango.
[dJango Snippet - Recaptcha](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/433/)

The view which is showing the page is -
from baseapp.recaptcha import captcha

```
def showHome(request):    
    if(request.user.is_authenticated()):    
        tempEmail = request.session.get('id')    
        return render_to_response('logreg/login-register.html',   {'emailFromForm':tempEmail}, context_instance=RequestContext(request));    
    else:    
        request.session.set_test_cookie()    
        form = RegistrationForm()    
        loginForm = LoginForm()    
        html_captcha = captcha.displayhtml(settings.RECAPTCHA_PUB_KEY)    
        print "Captcha HTML is : %s" % html_captcha    
        return render_to_response('logreg/login-register.html', {'form': form, 'loginForm':loginForm, 'html_captcha':html_captcha})    `
```

Here is the code in html -

```
<div id="register-dialog" title="Register yourself">    
  <p id="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>    
  {% if error %}    
  {{ error }}    
  {% endif %}    
  <form name="registrationForm" action="registerUser/" method="post">    
      {{ form.as_p }}    
      {{ html_captcha }}    
  </form>    
</div>
```

It works great in IE & Chrome, but firefox shows me an exception at line 451 in recaptcha.
Here is the code at that line `var $ST = RecaptchaState;`

Any thoughts are appreciated !

Note : Firefox version - 3.6; IE - 8; Chrome - 4.0

Comment: can you post the generated HTML/JavaScript? that's what Firefox is throwing the error on.

Comment: From firebug it showed that there was no other code generated. It took me straight to this line in recaptcha.js.
It was a bit confusing.
I'm not sure in what sequence FF loads the code, and downloading the js before anything else is an issue. Just speculating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.

I figured that my captcha is being shown inside the jqueryui dialog and maybe that is the problem with FF. (Why ? I don't know.)
Hence instead of statically putting the text there from django or writing it out.
I used the `ajax api` and inserted the recaptcha on the `open` event on the dialog.

Here is the sample code, just in case someone stumbles upon the same issue.

Code is almost similar to what is on the [reCaptcha api site](http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/client.html)

```
$("#register-dialog").dialog({    
    buttons:{
    },    
    open: function() {
    Recaptcha.create("41x39....",
        "recaptcha_div", {
        theme: "red",
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });
```

And changed the form tag to be so -

```
<form name="registrationForm" action="registerUser/" method="post">    
    {{ form.as_p }}    
    <div id="recaptcha_div"></div>    
</form>
```

And yes, included the ajax.js -

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/js/recaptcha_ajax.js">
    </script>
```